# PLC S7-1500 SQL-Connection - received data shifted by 1 byte --why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, plc, siemens, tia-portal

i´ve been successfully using a S7 1500 PLC in combination with an SQL-Server for quiete some time now.
I set everything up like mentioned here: [S7SQL-Guide-Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62403650/connecting-an-plc-siemens-s7-1500-to-an-sql-server-database)
Today i tried to add a second parameter to my SQL-Query. So I made something like this:

```
select Number1,Number2 from MYTABLE WHERE Apple = red and Sky = blue
```

The S7 sends the telegram, and the SQL-Server replies. So far so good.

[image: TokenColumnMetaData]

I set up the size of TokenColumnMetaData accordingly to my wireshark record,
compiled and send the updates to my PLC.
Now the part which I don´t understand:

I am expecting to receive the value "12345"
so again I used wireshark to see what I should expect:
[image: wireshark-data]

So what I got is: 39 30 00 00, which is 12345 just the bytes are reversed -no problem so far, but when I check on S7-side, I see this: [image: S7-Watchtable]

My input is shifted by 1 Byte.
How can I solve this?
Unfortantely I don´t have deeper knowledge of the code provided by Siemens for this application.

Edit:

Screenshot of typeUseCaseSpecificTokenrow

[image: typeUseCaseSpecificTokenrow]

Comment: Did you adjust the `typeUseCaseSpecificTokenRow` struct after adding the `Number2` bigint column? Seems like it's still expecting rows of `int` (1 length byte + 4 data bytes) instead of rows with both `int` and `bigint` (2 length bytes + 12 data bytes).

Comment: I tried, but with no positive outcome for my problem.

Comment: Can you [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70708709/edit) your question to include a screen shot of the `typeUseCaseSpecificTokenRow` struct inside "PLC data types"? According to your Wireshark capture there should only be one row in the results. Starting with the `d1 ROW` token at `008D` is the `int` value with a length of `04` and the data `39 30 00 00` (1234), followed by the `bigint` value with a length of `08` and the data `47 94 03 00 00 00 00 00` (60049160). The `tokenRows` array data doesn't seem to agree with this, though, because it's only showing what it thinks are `int` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes weird memory stuff happens when the data type comprises an odd number of bytes.

Siemens starts each element on an even memory address. So if `Length` is at address 0 and `Data` is at 2-5, then address 1 may be getting the first byte that is intended for Data

| Address | Data | Element |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00 | 04 | Length 0 |
| 01 | 39 |  |
| 02 | 30 | Data 0, byte 0 |
| 03 | 00 | Data 0, byte 1 |
| 04 | 00 | Data 0, byte 2 |
| 05 | 08 | Data 0, byte 3 |
| 06 | 47 | Length 1 |
| 07 | 94 |  |
| 08 | 03 | Data 1, byte 0 |
| 09 | 00 | Data 1, byte 1 |
| 10 | 00 | Data 1, byte 2 |
| 11 | 00 | Data 1, byte 3 |
| 12 | 00 | Length 2 |
| 13 | 00 |  |
| 14 | FD | Data 2, byte 0 |
| 15 | 10 | Data 2, byte 1 |
| 16 | 00 | Data 2, byte 2 |
| 17 | C1 | Data 2, byte 3 |

Comment: Is there a solution for this ? Currently I adjusted everything in a way, that I can access the bytes that I really need(the other bytes are inaccessable on siemens side now) but that´s more a workaround than a solution.

Comment: One option is to send all the data to an array of bytes, then write an FB to move that data into a tag of your user data type. It does mean you're storing the information twice though.